# WWDR Intermediate Certificate not found Error - IOS Simulator Launch Issue

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, titanium

When I'm trying to launch simulator from VSCode with Titanium SDK I'm seeing the following error:
[image: error message]

`Download and install the certificate from http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer`

How to fix this. The certificate that I'm installing is not supporting.

Answer (score 0):

Check Apples site https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ and download `Worldwide Developer Relations - G2 (Expiring 05/06/2029 23:43:24 UTC)` (direkt link https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG2.cer)

The other link just expired some days ago

Edit: [a fix was pushed](https://github.com/tidev/titanium_mobile/pull/13747) to the SDK itself so the link will be fixed in the next release