# Unable to launch iPhone Simulator with Titanium app

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium

When trying to run the iPhone simulator for my Titanium app, I get the following error:

**[ERROR] WWDR Intermediate Certificate not found**

**Download and install the certificate from https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG2.cer**

Even after downloading and installing the certificate in my keychain app, the error persists.

I found someone else asked about this issue a few months ago, and the response was, "a fix was pushed to the SDK itself so the link will be fixed in the next release."

[WWDR Intermediate Certificate not found Error - IOS Simulator Launch Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75433379/wwdr-intermediate-certificate-not-found-error-ios-simulator-launch-issue)

However, since that response was posted, I downloaded Titanium SDK 12.1.1.GA, and the error persists. When I looked at GitHub to see what was included in the fix, there were only two changes to the source code, which look like changes to output messages about the correct URL to use for downloading the certificate. Nothing looked like it actually fixed the search for the correct certificate.

https://github.com/tidev/titanium-sdk/pull/13747

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate has nothing todo with Titanium, it is a Apple certificate and you can try one of the other WWDRC files from https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ (right side: "Worldwide Developer Relations", pick e.g. G3).

> Nothing looked like it actually fixed the search for the correct certificate.

The fix in the PR was done by me and it just fixed the link to the new certificate as the old link links to an outdated one.

Once you've installed the WWDRC certificate make sure to check your keychain to see that is installed correctly.

edit:
also make sure to check https://stackoverflow.com/a/67334871/5193915

Comment: Thanks. Using the link [https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer) instead of the one provided in the error message fixed the issue for me. I appreciate your prompt response.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll update the link in the SDK